# storage image not showing in laravel

Tags: laravel, image

my image get store in the storage/app/public/receptionistprofile/image name but when i call it in blade it gives me 404 eror why so??

blade code below [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

every things was good, i figure out that the image was being uploaded in the storage/app/public/receptionistprofile/image_name but it was not being updated to the public/storage/receptionistprofile/image_name, so i have  deleted the storage folder that resides in the public directory and again created the system links , now all works good

Answer (score 0):

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

> php artisan storage:link

you have written wrong path you are missing: /app/public/

```
<img  src="{{url('/storage/app/public/receptionistprofile/'.$receptionis->avatar)}}" alt="">
```